# photo library like swipe taking time delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've made a image gallery with a swipe effect to skip through the uiimageviews.i am using a scrollview to do this.adding all my images in to scrollview using a for loop and am inabling the pagesEnabled=true
      myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

**but it is taking more time in the case of multiple images.**

i have a gallery page and preview page .when ever user clicking the thumb image in gallery page it will navigates to preview page .am doing the looping in preview page's view did load.but it is stucking in gallery page itself and after creating all the images inside scrollview it is showing the preview page.

my question is **is there any way to avoid the time delay.??**
or **there is any way to load all the images after getting inside the preview page(then  i can show some loading symbol there insted of stuking and showing the galllery)**.

Comment: you should add the images asynchrony like a UITableView: http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-ipad-appstore-like-uiscrollview-with-paging-and-preview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to restrict your drawing to only those images currently on the screen. It takes time and memory to draw the images you can't see, and so, the more you add, the slower everything gets, for no benefit. There have been a number of good WWDC presentations on this in the last couple of years. Go to iTunes U (in iTunes) and sign up for the WWDC 2010 and WWDC 2011 videos. Look for ones on implementing scrolling and scrolling performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many images in the best thing is only to load 3 Images and then to replace the images when you are scrolling to the next. You can check out the Apple WWDC Session 104 for more information about this.